# Как объяснить IDE PHPStorm, что функция в проекте вызывается, но не напрямую, а через название в строке?

Tags: wordpress, phpstorm, phpdoc

В работе с **Wordpress** хуки на различные системные события записываются следующим образом:

`do_action('hook_event_title', 'my_custom_function_title');`

Можно ли как-то дать понять IDE PHPStorm, что функция `my_custom_function_title` вызывается, но не через прямой вызов? Возможно, поможет PHPDoc.

Сейчас название функции подсвечивается серым, будто она не вызывается, и это может вызвать проблемы при рефакторинге. Задача — избавиться от этого.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно убрать эту инспекцию
**Settings** -> **Editor** -> **Inspections** -> **PHP** -> **unused declaration**

---

**Используй wodpress плагин.**

**Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP**

[image: Плагин для phpstorm]

---

Также еще можно было сделать новый файл **_ide_helper.php**, и там вызвать ее, тем самым дать понять IDE PHPStorm, что она используется. Этот файл нигде не должен подключатся.

Answer (score 6):

**Settings** -> **Languages & Frameworks** -> **PHP**

Укажи путь к папке WordPress'а

**Settings** -> **Languages & Frameworks** -> **PHP** -> **Framework**

Укажи путь к папке WordPress'а